# ffmpeg played AVI video faster than the video is recorded

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I am working an embedded Linux system (kerne-5.10.24).
Now I am testing the video recording and playing.

I recorded a video with command,

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 640x480 -r 30 -vcodec mjpeg -i /dev/video3 -b:v 1000k -an /tmp/videocap.avi
```

Then, I played the video with ffmpeg as follows,

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/videocap.avi  -pix_fmt bgra -f fbdev /dev/fb0
```

I found the video is played much faster then it is recorded, as follows,

```
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
Input #0, avi, from '/tmp/videocap.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1036 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1029 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0xbd87a0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra.
Output #0, fbdev, to '/dev/fb0':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGRA / 0x41524742), bgra, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 294912 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
frame=310 fps= 90 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:10.33 bitrate=N/A speed=2.99x
video:372000kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

The `speed=2.99x`.....
And I also tried the commands like,

```
# ffmpeg -i videocap.avi -vf "setpts=0.5*PTS" videocap2.avi
....
Output #0, avi, to 'videocap2.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  156 fps= 35 q=24.8 Lsize=389kB time=00:00:05.20 bitrate= 612.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=154 speed=1.16x
video:379kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.467023%
```

But playing `ffmpeg -i /tmp/videocap2.avi  -pix_fmt bgra -f fbdev /dev/fb0` got the same result, no slowing down.

So how to replay the video as the same speed (FPS) as it is recorded ?

#### Change to use -framerate.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 640x480 -framerate 30 -vcodec mjpeg -i /dev/video3 -b:v 1000k /tmp/videocap.avi

  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video3':
  Duration: N/A, start: 61.843846, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x105f790] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, avi, to '/tmp/videocap.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 1000 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=99 fps=5.3 q=4.2 Lsize=852kB time=00:00:11.83 bitrate= 590.1kbits/s speed=0.634x
video:839kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.659792%
```

Then play back the videocap.avi as follows,

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/videocap.avi -pix_fmt bgra -f fbdev /dev/fb0

  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Input #0, avi, from '/tmp/videocap.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 590 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 582 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1a1b6f0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra.
Output #0, fbdev, to '/dev/fb0':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGRA / 0x41524742), bgra, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 294912 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
frame=   99 fps= 82 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:11.83 bitrate=N/A speed=9.77x
video:118800kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

`-r` says, according to `man ffmpeg`,

> As an input option, ignore any timestamps stored in the file and instead generate timestamps assuming constant frame rate fps.  This is not the same as the -framerate option used for some input formats like image2 or v4l2 (it used to be the same in older versions of FFmpeg).  If in doubt use -framerate instead of the input option -r.

In other words, you **told** ffmpeg that the input frames came in at 30 fps. But they weren't. Ffmpeg doesn't care about the real rate of frames, it just encodes the frames it gets and puts the framerate you told it into the file.

At playback, 30 frames are played per second, no matter how long it took on the recording side to actually get 30 frames.

In other words, don't use `-r` at all, and only if you really know what you're doing, use `-framerate`.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I updated question with result of using `-framerate`, I am not sure if I am using it in the right way, but the playback is still much faster than recorded.  Did I use the right command to do the recording ?